# php string to time issue

Tags: php, date

I have a date string what I would like to convert in digits. The string looks like

```
Dienstag, 30. Oktober 2012
```

and the code what I've been trying to use

```
date('Y.m.d' , strtotime($str[4]));
```

returns every time `1970.01.01`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this by changing the current *locale set* http://php.net/manual/bg/function.setlocale.php
If you know the source date format you can also stick to using https://www.php.net/date_create_from_format

Here is more details regarding the same question [strtotime With Different Languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988536/strtotime-with-different-languages)

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` takes string in English language. Look at possible [date/time formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

Comment: thanks for the feedback. could I use setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE")? to get my string converted

Answer (score 0):

use strtotime() to convert the date into timestamp

$ts = strtotime('21 december 2007');
echo date('Y-m-d', $ts);

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
$str= 'Dienstag, 30. Oktober 2012';

echo date('Y.m.d' , strtotime($str[4]));   
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using a French locale when the date is in German?

Comment: <?php
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');
    $str= 'Dienstag, 30. Oktober 2012';

    echo date('Y.m.d' , strtotime($str[4]));   
    ?>  //2012.11.28// check this

Comment: and what return str[4] for you?

Comment: why don u echo n check the output??