# How do I translate PHP strtotime to local language

Tags: php

I have this line

```
<?php
echo date('H:i, d F Y',strtotime($i->date_start));
?>
```

Which outputs:

```
20:24, Saturday, 07 December 2013
```

How do I translate it to my local language?

Comment: Please show an attempt to solve the problem yourself before your ask here. Here's a link to the PHP manual for the `date` function, it will contain everything you need: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php - and `setlocate` for your language: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: I did not found how to translate it, and I do not now the location of the strtotime function to be able to translate it, I only have this line and I don`t know what to try! I suck

Comment: Look up `setlocate`, read the manual for it, and call it above your code. Don't bother with `strtotime`

Comment: I also tried translating joomla names for month names with no effect

Comment: How does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988536/strtotime-with-different-languages aswer my question !?

Answer (score 1):

You could use str_ireplace with an array of searches and an array of replacements.

```
$monthsDaysEn = array('January','February','March','Saturday','etc'); //populate with all months/days you want translated
$monthsDaysEs = array('enero','febero','marzo','Sabado','etc'); //populate in same order with their counterparts

$datestr = "20:24, Saturday, 07 March 2013";

$translated = str_ireplace($monthsEn,$monthsEs,$datestr);

echo $translated;
```

Comment: I tried this `<?php setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ro_RO'); echo date($par->get('date_format','Y-m-d H:i:s'),strftime($i->date_mod)); ?>` nad it does not work...

Comment: If you don't want the headache of trying to get setlocal to work this solution is quite good.

Comment: Just a correction - you are using $monthsDaysEn when declaring you variable but $monthsEn later in str_ireplace, it should be the same.