# Converting String to DateFormat

Tags: php

I have this data 
| 01 Oktober 2017 |

This is an Indonesian date

And i want to convert into dateformat. And so the result must be 2017-10-01.
Can you please help ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Use `strtotime()` Php Function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to Date and DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime)

Comment: this is an indonesian date, in datepicker, language set it to (id). i use strtotime it gives me result 1970-01-01. and this is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert dates with the month name in Indonesian into PHP readable date formats.

```
function getDate($indonesianMonthName){

  setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');

  $month_numbers = range(1,12);

  foreach($month_numbers as $month)
    $english_months[] = strftime('%B',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,2011));

  setlocale(LC_ALL, 'Indonesian');

  foreach($month_numbers as $month)
    $indonesian_months[] = strftime('%B',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,2011));

  return str_replace($indonesian_months, $english_months, $indonesianMonthName);

}

echo getDate('01 Desember 2017');
echo getDate('01 Oktober 2017');
```

So basically, you create an array of every single month and its corresponding value in English and Indonesian, and then you use `str_replace()` to *"translate"* the date into English.

You can now use regulat `strtotime()` and `Date()` functions on the returned string.

References : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39874682/6124528

Answer (score -1):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php),

```
$date = strtotime($_POST['fixtureDate']);
    $fixtureDate = date("Y-m-j", $date);
```

You can then play with the format so that it displays how you want it to

Comment: A comment should have worked perfectly + link-only answers are evil. Imagine once the target page gets deleted, so you will have a dead link. Put the essential part of the target page into your answer. Whit such answer you are decreasing the quality of SO

Comment: this is an indonesian date, in datepicker, language set it to (id). i use strtotime it gives me result 1970-01-01. and this is wrong

Comment: hey, you need to update the format "Y-m-j". Have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: The date is in Indonesian, you cannot merely `strtotime()` it.